# Purple screen appears while booting into Windows 10 on dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have installed the latest Ubuntu LTS version on dual boot with my 64-bit Windows 10 Pro. 
Laptop specs-Dell Latitude E7440, i5-4200U with integrated graphics card. Windows is installed in C drive and Ubuntu on D-drive. When I select Windows 10 option from the Grub boot menu, it displays a dotted purple screen for a few seconds and then Windows loads. I have attached the image of it too. Please explain me the proper steps as I'm new to the Ubuntu OS and don't know any commands etc.

[image]

Comment: I'm still experiencing this problem after my laptop's BIOS update. Help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot into Ubuntu by selecting it from the GRUB menu (GRUB menu screenshot in step 4).
2. Open the terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l`
3. Restart your system with `sudo reboot`
4. After loading you will be asked to select a boot option. Select Windows 10 from the GRUB menu.

   [image]
5. It may boot into safe mode.
6. In Windows 10 Start menu type *System Configuration* -> select *Boot* tab -> uncheck *Safe boot* -> click *Apply* button -> click *OK* button.

   [image]
7. Reboot again with `sudo reboot`.